# Excel compare value of columns on sheet 1 and 2 and on match copy data from different column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

What I want to do sounds very simply but I'm having a hard time pulling it off.

On sheet 1 I have a bunch of IP addresses in column A and some other data like ports, packets size etc in column B, C, D etc. A lot of IP addresses are duplicates but with different packet and port values.

On sheet 2 I have the domain data for the IP addresses.

Column A contains IP addresses, Column B and C the domain data.

What I want to do is compare the IP addresses on Sheet 1 and 2 and if they match I want sheet 2 column B and C to be copied to a empty cell on sheet 1 matching that IP.

In short I want all the domain data from sheet 2 copied to the row on sheet 1 with the matching IP.

Save me! :D

Comment: Go watch the video on the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumptions**

- Your data begins in cell A1 of Sheet1
- Column E is the first column with blank data in Sheet1; that is, we will want the data from column B of Sheet2 to end up in column E of Sheet1.

**Solution**

Enter the following formula in cell E1 of Sheet1: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"No Match")`

Enter the following formula in cell F1 of Sheet1: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"No Match")`

These formulas will return the data from columns B and C of Sheet2 when column A of Sheet1 matches column A of Sheet2.

Comment: Thanks Nick,

This works but only on a per cell basis. I have over 10.000 entries in sheet1 that need to be compared against a list of about 600 entries in sheet2.

I tried changing the range from A1 to A:A but unfortunately its not that simply.

Comment: @sjaak could you not extend the formula from E1 to E1:E10000? If you are trying to minimize the load on Excel, you can also specify the exact ranges in the Index/Match formulas (i.e. `INDEX(Sheet2!B1:B600`).

Comment: I think I messed up, tried again after changing A1 to A:A and properly selecting the whole E column and it appears to be working now. 

Thanks a million :)

Comment: @sjaak Ah, stellar! Glad to help :)